# Google results shows Meteor.js site as "Loading..."

Tags: node.js, meteor, google-search

I submitted a Meteor.js site (based on [Telescope](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope)) to Google and in the search results, Google have the site pages crawled as having the title `Loading...` and only static content (instead of dynamically loaded ones) were in Google's description of the site.

`mrt list --using` shows that `spiderable` is already being used.

Is it possible to let google retrieve the actual title of the page?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You should use the [spiderable](http://docs.meteor.com/#spiderable) package.

You can check if your configuration works by adding the escaped fragment parameter. For instance for the documentation: http://docs.meteor.com/?_escaped_fragment_=

Comment: `mrt list --using` shows that `spiderable` is already being used.

Comment: Where do you run your application? Meteor cloud solution or your own server?

Comment: Run it on my own Ubuntu server.

Comment: So you need to install phantomjs on your server `sudo apt-get install phantomjs`.

Comment: Did you test `?_escaped_fragment_=` ?